# issue with spinner in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to select an item in the spinner and then write it in a `TextView` but I have an error.

```
 Spinner spinner = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner);
        TextView mytext = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        List<string> dataList = new List<string>();

        dataList.Add("2");
        dataList.Add("1");
        dataList.Add("3");
        var ArrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem, dataList);
        spinner.Adapter = ArrayAdapter1;
        if (spinner.SelectedItem.Equals("2"))

            mytext.Text = "click 2";

        if (spinner.SelectedItem.Equals("1"))

            mytext.Text = "click 1";
```

Comment: *"...but I have an error."* you should always include the error in your posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to subscribe to the `ItemSelected` event and there validate for the item that was selected.

Try this:

```
spinner.ItemSelected += (sender, e) => {

    var itemSelected = (string) spinner.SelectedItem;

    if (itemSelected == "1")
    {
        textView.Text = "Clicked 1";
    }
    else if (itemSelected == "2")
    {
        textView.Text = "Clicked 2";
    }
};
```

**UPDATE**

To use is inside a button click event handler method you just need to:

Make both your textView and your spinner a private field in the class, so it can be accessed from another place is your code and add this code below inside your method:

```
var itemSelected = (string) spinner.SelectedItem;
if (itemSelected == "1")
{
    textView.Text = "Clicked 1";
}
else if (itemSelected == "2")
{
    textView.Text = "Clicked 2";
}
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: hi,i can not use (sender,e).    because  i want use it in..... public void button1click(object sender, EventArgs e){....HERE...}

Comment: do you have another solution

Comment: i add  private Spinner spinner;         but when i click button i have this error  http://uupload.ir/files/bo3n_capture.jpg